# ionic 2: Disable swipe back in <ion-item-sliding>

Tags: ionic2

I am using ionic 2 ion-item-sliding with ion-item and ion-item-options for swipping and show two buttons and text box as follows. My problem is when I click the text box which is in the ion-item-options list, whole component swipe back, so i cant enter any data inside the text box. How can i prevent swiping back until i enter data in text box?

```
<ion-item-sliding #item *ngFor="let order of orders">
  <ion-item>

    <div class="pending-order-list">
      <div class="row custom-padding-xs custom-padding">
        <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <div class="panel-order-date">
            <span class="list-label">{{ "pendingOrder.date" | translate }}</span>
            <span class="list-input">{{ order.orderDate | date }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-order-number">
            <span class="list-label">{{ "pendingOrder.orderNo" | translate }}</span>
            <span class="list-input">{{order.orderNo}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row custom-padding-xs">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <span class="list-label">{{ "pendingOrder.customer" | translate }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 bold">
          {{order.customer}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 bold text-right">
          {{order.sum | numberFormat}}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row custom-padding-xs">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <span class="list-label">{{ "pendingOrder.chain" | translate }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 ">
          {{order.chain}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 status">
          {{order.status}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="right">
    <div class="row custom-padding-xs">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" name="" id="" class="input-custom" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button class="btn-small" (click)="confirmOrder(order)">{{ "pendingOrder.confirm" | translate }}</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button class="btn-small black">{{ "pendingOrder.reject" | translate }}</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </ion-item-options>
```

Comment: unlike you my ionic app sliding stayed and i want to swip back automatically. but this stayed on sqip state